# How to clump a series of messages

Tags: c#, math, testing, scheduling, messaging

I am writing a test application for stress-testing a server. I have a list of messages which I need to send in a given time interval, but I am interested in not just sending them with a uniform gap, but "clumping" messages together to simulate bursts. This will be controlled by a slider in the UI - at one end is uniform, at the other is "clumpy". Is there a neat mathematical way to do this?

Comment: So, how's this related to programming? At least tag the question with a programming-langauge...

Comment: FWIW, C#. But it could be any language. It's "programming" because I'm writing code to do it, I guess?

Comment: You probably want something like an Erlang Distribution (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution) of messages arriving at your server.  If not, the Wikipedia article will point you onwards in our researches.

Comment: Can you give us more information? What kind of "messages" are these? Do you want to do this in terms of a network protocol, or just have a string message that's "clumped"?

Comment: The messages are just XML strings. There's no need for a protocol, I just need to adjust the time between sending messages so that at one end of the scale they arrive equally spaced, and at the other end they arrive in groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So lets say that you have slider, max,  a time interval T that you can cut up in to N divisions, and a total number of message M you want to send.  Then at time division N, I would send

```
(M/N)*(max(1-slider/max)+k*(slider/max)cosine(PI*N/T))
```

When slider=0, this will give total uniformity, with M/N messages arriving each interval.  When slider=max, the uniformity will be completely damped, and you can adjust the parameter k to make the clumping even more extreme.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think could work:

```
var rngClumpMax = new Random();
var clumpMin = 1;
var clumpMax = 1;
var clumpSize = 1;

clumpSize = rngClumpMax.Next(clumpMin, clumpMax);

while (true)
{
    List<string> messages = FetchMessages(clumpSize);
    if (messages.Count > 0)
    {
        SendMessages(messages);
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

The scrollbar could set the value of `clumpMax`, so you can generate clumps between sizes of 1 and some `N` value from the scrollbar.

If you had a control with double scrolls, you could set even `clumpMin` and generate a random `clumpSize` between `clumpMin` and `clumpMax`.